# Как отловить смену языка в приложении

Tags: android

Я хочу отловить смену языка в приложении , чтобы в дальнейшем сделать исключение, каким образом это можно сделать? Посоветуйте пример какой нибудь.

Comment: вы его меняете программно? или на уровне системы?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как отловить смену языка в активности и переключиться на новое соединение для сервера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1073849/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%83-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%b5)

Comment: @Andrew- Программно меняю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно решить вопрос так:

```
Locale current = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
```

Вот [обсуждение_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690460/how-to-get-language-locale-currently-android-app-displays) и [обсуждение_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14389349/android-get-current-locale-not-default) где указана интересующая вас информация

Answer (score 0):

При запуске Application вытягиваем локаль, делаем овверайд onConfigurationChanged

```
Locale current;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
   current = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
   Locale mayBeNewLocale = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
   if (!mayBeNewLocale.getLanguage().equals(current.getLanguage())) {
      // что нужно делаем
   }
}
```

Comment: можете подробней описать ваш метод? А ту я что то не пойму.

Comment: У вас должен быть наследник Application. При старте приложения вы вытягиваете локаль и если в системе сменился язык то будет вызван onConfigurationChanged и там тоже тянете уже новую локаль, сравниваете язвки если разные делае то что вам нужно при смене языка